# Duplicates not allowed error in ng-repeat when list of objects in an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am confused why ng-repeat is giving me duplicates error. I can solve it using `track by $index` but I want to know when this error is thrown by angular.

**This is clear**

```
<div ng-repeat="a in [1,1,1,1]">...</div>
```

As there are duplicates value in above array, it will definitely throw an `Dups` error.

**What about list of objects**

```
<div ng-repeat="a in items">...</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.items = [
                   {"ab":1,"bc":3},
                   {"ab":1,"bc":3}
               ]
```

How does angular treats/compare second one to decide whether there are duplicate values or not?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Why I am not getting duplication error?

[<kbd>Fiddle DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/z9cGm/79/)

Comment: Above List object example not giving any error
check @ http://jsfiddle.net/z9cGm/78/

Comment: Now tell me why its not giving duplication error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I clear concepts myself.

Angular checks weather reference of the object is same or not. So however in my case there are two objects which is same but both are pointing to different reference so its not giving duplicate error. See updated fiddle.

```
function AController($scope) {
    var a = {"ab":1,"bc":3}
    var b = a;
    $scope.objsInObj = [
                   a,
                   b
               ]

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z9cGm/82/)

Comment: In above case, in ng-repeat when object "a" in Iteration angular adds $$hashKey to "a", when "b" in iteration it which is pointing to "a", which already Has $$hashkey, so angular will not add new $$hashkey and return "a's" Hashkey so it will be Duplicate, so Angular Raise duplicate Error

Answer (score 4):

See this tutorial http://www.anujgakhar.com/2013/06/15/duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed-in-angularjs/ .

In your case, because your two objects have the same key values (`ab`) you get the error. Adding a `track by $index` might solve the problem.

**EDIT**

From the source code.

> variable in expression track by tracking_expression` – You can also provide an optional tracking function
>    *     which can be used to associate the objects in the collection with the DOM elements. If no tracking function
>    *     is specified the ng-repeat associates elements by identity in the collection. It is an error to have
>    *     more than one tracking function to resolve to the same key. (This would mean that two distinct objects are
>    *     mapped to the same DOM element, which is not possible.)  Filters should be applied to the expression,
>    *     before specifying a tracking expression.

As I understand it, two elements in  the repeat resolve to the same tracking id (`$$hashkey` I believe) you will get the error. You should really check out their source code. It's pretty well commented and annotated.

Comment: you are right. track by $index will solve my problem but I want to know concepts behind duplicates error thrown by angular in case of list of objects.

Comment: You can check out Angular's own source for ng-repeat https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js. The error is thrown around line 310.

Comment: Now check, I made a fiddle. if you can help me to clear my concepts.

Comment: If you use Batarang you can see the id's created by `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 3):

In angular for each object Means(`JSON`,`object hasOwnProperty`), angular maintaining unique ID that `$$hashKey` used for tracking each object and bind it with DOM element, so as for below case :

```
$scope.items = [
                   {"ab" : 1", "bc" : 3},
                   {"ab" : 1, "bc" : 3}
               ]
```

While Angular is not maintenance unique ID for Simple Array

```
$scope.simpleArrray=[1, 1, 1, 1];
```

In `ng-repeat` angularJS maintains Hash for each item Iterate and check for uniqueness for `JSON object` or `Array`, if Duplicate ID found in case of simple array it raise an error, for any `JSON object` its added Unique ID if not found, so you are not getting duplicate error in `JSON object`

Hope i have clarified your doubts

```
function AController($scope) {
    var a = {"ab" : 1, "bc" :3}
    var b = a;
    $scope.objsInObj = [
                   a,
                   b
               ]    
}
```

In above case, in `ng-repeat` when object `a` in Iteration angular adds `$$hashKey` to `a`, when `b` in iteration it which is pointing to `a`, which already Has `$$hashkey`, so angular will not add new `$$hashkey` and return `a's` Hashkey so it will be Duplicate, so Angular Raise duplicate Error

Comment: Still not clear what you are talking about. My simple question is why I am not getting error of duplication. According to what I understood, I should get an error.

Comment: Very nice answer, for who working with `JSON` and get the `ng-repeat dups error` and didn't find this answer useful, I suggest read the answer again.